# Is there a case in which a Reducible Markov Chain has a unique limiting distribution?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Generally a Reducible Markov Chain has a limiting distribution but it changes with different initial distribution. But is there a case in which a Reducible Markov Chain has a unique limiting distribution ? If the answer is yes, can you give me an example of such Markov Chain and how to find the Steady-State Distribution ?

Comment: Simple example is a transient chain with a single closed class.

Comment: In fact that's the only possible collection of examples for this property.

Comment: As an exercise, I recommend you prove what @Ian stated (it shouldn't be difficult).

Comment: thank you guys !